# VBA - Cut & Paste cells between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim wbTarget As Workbook 
Dim wbSource As Workbook

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\alibe\Desktop\PoS\Alain.xlsx")

wbSource.Worksheets("Spain").Range("plage_sp").Copy
wbSource.Activate

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
wbTarget.Worksheets("Feui1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close
```

Hi everybody,

I am trying to cut and paste cells between two different workbooks. But I got failure 9 or 438 in my Paste line. May somebody give a help please.

Comment: Why are you activating the source workbook after you copy from it? Get rid of that line. Instead activate the target workbook.

Comment: `wbSource.Activate` and the 2nd `Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook` are useless. Change `Worksheets()` to `Sheets()`. And you are most likely to have a typo there : `Sheets("Feui1")` should be `Sheets("Feuil1")`, you miss an `L` ;)

Comment: Is the format important to you? There are faster ways of doing this that don't involve copy+pasta.

Comment: don't you mean cut and paste? cut implies copy as far as I'm aware

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Few changes

```
Dim wbTarget As Workbook 
Dim wbSource As Workbook

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\alibe\Desktop\PoS\Alain.xlsx")

wbSource.Sheets("Spain").Range("plage_sp").Copy
wbTarget.Sheets("Feui1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close
```

Comment: Have you changed anything other then the double variable settings? It would be helpful to give an explanation alongside your code

Comment: Yes.changed the Worksheets to sheets and added Paste:=xlPasteAll

Comment: I'm afraid I have a strong suspicion this isn't the issue

Comment: Run it and comment again with your findings. I am sorry but, being suspicious is not the proof of "code not working".

Comment: I am not sure, but my testing is successful after setting the range properly in the line: wbSource.Sheets("Spain").Range("plage_sp").Copy

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things we want change.

First, it's good practice to get into the habit of having excel check whether your file location exists or not. You might think you have it put in correctly, but it's always best to make sure excel feels the same way. (This also makes your code more flexible for later use.)

When opening workbooks and closing them, there's no reason to bog your system down trying to open new windows quickly. Since we don't need to see what it's doing, just that it's done it, we can turn `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts` to false until the end of our code.

You should check the spelling on your worksheet "Feui1", that it's not actually "Feuil".

For the application of defining different ranges by workbook, we need to use `.Sheets()` object instead of `.Worksheets()`

Also, it's not common to see that you have this code in the same file that you're closing, when you're opening another file. At the end of this routine, `ThisWorkbook` is going to close, and `wbSource` will be left open. Is this intentional? Just something I thought I'd point out.

```
Sub CopyPasta()
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook: Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, sourceFile As String

    sourceFile = "C:\Users\alibe\Desktop\PoS\Alain.xlsx"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Dir(sourceFile) = "" Then 'Checks that file location exists
        MsgBox "File not found.", vbCritical, "Bad File Address"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sourceFile)

    wbSource.Sheets("Spain").Range("plage_sp").Copy

    wbTarget.Sheets("Feuil").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Spelling on 'Feuil'

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbTarget.Save
    wbTarget.Close 'You want to close the workbook that this code is in?
End Sub
```